# C# code returns out of method when value is too large

Tags: c#

I got a small method that splits a string into two parts, retrieves one part and uses it to establish a connection to a server:

```
private void RetrieveData(string vesselCode)
{
    string[] splitSelectedVessel = vesselCode.Split('_');
    int selectedVessel = int.Parse(splitSelectedVessel[1]);

    // URL of server to retrieve data.
    // constructed with vesselCode.
    string baseUrl = ".../vehicle/";
    string jsonUrl = baseUrl + selectedVessel;

    PtVehicle currentVessel = DownloadAndDeserialize<PtVehicle>(jsonUrl);

}
```

VesselCode containts two parts, combined with an '_' in between:

- company code
- vesselnumber

Both are of entry fields from a Xamarin project and are originally stored as strings.

Whenever the VesselNumber part gets too large, it just stops right after `int selectedVessel = int.Parse(splitSelectedVessel[1]);`. It seems to break out of the method above, without giving a warning or anything. I've tested it with breakpoints on every line. It simply stops running that method and goes on with whatever it was doing, often letting the app crash later on (since it needs that value). What is happening here?

Comment: Its high time you start utilizing C# exception handling!! Also `string jsonUrl = baseUrl + selectedVessel;` looks fishy. Different types fed to operand `+`

Comment: how long? getting number part may throw exception in `int.Parse(splitSelectedVessel[1]);` if it gets out of int range, but must be no issue on split line.

Comment: Numbers can get however large the used fills in, there is no cap on that.

Comment: @sjsam I refactured a bit to parse selectedVessel as a string instead (fixed the issue too). Would the `string jsonUrl = baseUrl + selectedVessel;` still be bad code this way?

Comment: max int in c# is 2,147,483,647..try a long.

Comment: Yeah, that was indeed the issue. Since the vesselnumber acted as an ID and I didnt actually have to calculate anything with it I decided to store it in a astring

Comment: Please do not add answers to questions. If you feel that you hav some information not covered in accepted or other answers feel free to post another answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your number is all too long for an `int`. I don't know what can the maximum number be, but you can try `long` instead. Probably it's enough.

If it isn't then you have to do something with handling of too large numbers. You can write

```
if (long.TryParse(myString, out myValue)
{
   // Your logic here
}
else
{
   // Do something if the value is too large
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense (with MiHai's link). It indeed seems like the number was too large for an int to store. Knowing this I fixed the issue by parsing it as a string instead (I don't need to calculate anything with it, just using it for the connection and such).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing the issue with @Ilya Chernomordik's and the documentation provided by @Mihai.

The issue was that `int selectedVessel = int.Parse(splitSelectedVessel[1]);` parses the value of that string to an int. When the value was larger than the int max size, it crashed. Since VesselNumber is an ID and I don't have to calculate it, I simply solved it by storing it as a string:

```
string selectedVessel = splitSelectedVessel[1];
```

Another way is to store it as a long (int) of 64 bits, but this only "moves" the issue to a much larger number.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you are throwing an exception.  Consider the following code...

```
        try
        {
            string s1 = "2147483649";
            int j = int.Parse(s1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

2147483649 is int.MaxValue + 1

This code generates the following message:

```
Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

Comment: That is not a good solution, there is `int.TryParse` to avoid throwing exceptions

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik it is not a solution at all.  I'm simply answering the question "what is happening here?"

Comment: Right, I suppose the question was about what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

It should throw an `System.OverflowException` if the number is too big to be parsed as int. 
According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/integral-types-table) `long`/ `ulong` has the biggest range.

You might have breaking for exceptions disabled if you are using Visual Studio so you might want to enable them to see what's the actual problem `Debug->Windows->Exception Settings` and make sure Common Language Runtime Exceptions are checked.

On the other hand, the best practice is to use the `.TryParse` approach when converting to an integral type.